# select2 and datepicker not working inside ajax loaded modal window on codeigniter

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

i am trying to edit database value on ajax loaded modal window. the values retrieve fine and editing db contents also works . but the problem is on the value editing modal window,bootstrap datepicker and select2 plugin is not working. any suggestion is highly appreciated. Here is my code which calls the ajax loaded modal.

The view of modal window code is :

```
<?php 
$edit_data                =        $this->db->get_where('programs' , array('program_id' => $param2) )->result_array();
foreach ( $edit_data as $row):
?>
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="panel panel-primary" data-collapsed="0">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <div class="panel-title" >
                            <i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i>
                                        <?php echo get_phrase('edit_program');?>
                    </div>
            </div>
                        <div class="panel-body">

                <?php echo form_open(base_url() . 'index.php?admin/programs/do_update/'.$row['program_id'] , array('autocomplete'=>'off','target'=>'_top'));?>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-sm-4 control-label"><?php echo get_phrase('program_title');?></label>
                        <div class="col-sm-8">
                            <div class="inputer">
                                <div class="input-wrapper">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="program_name" value="<?php echo $row['name']; ?>">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-sm-4 control-label"><?php echo get_phrase('numeric_code');?></label>
                        <div class="col-sm-8">
                            <div class="inputer">
                                <div class="input-wrapper">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="numeric_code" value="<?php echo $row['numeric_code']; ?>">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div  class="col-lg-12 form-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-university" aria-hidden="true"></i>  <?php echo get_phrase('select_board'); ?></span>

                            <select data-placeholder="Select Board" name="board_id" class="chosen-select">
                                    <option disabled selected>Select Board</option>
                                    <?php 
                                        $boards = $this->db->get('boards')->result_array();
                                        foreach($boards as $row2):
                                    ?>
                                    <option value="<?php echo $row2['board_id'];?>"
                                        <?php if($row['board_id'] == $row2['board_id'])echo 'selected';?>>
                                            <?php echo $row2['name'];?>
                                                </option>
                                    <?php
                                    endforeach;
                                    ?>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-sm-4 control-label"><?php echo get_phrase('no._of_years');?></label>
                        <div class="col-sm-8">
                            <div class="inputer">
                                <div class="input-wrapper">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="no_of_years" value="<?php echo $row['no_of_years']; ?>">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-sm-4 control-label"><?php echo get_phrase('no_of_admission_per_year');?></label>
                        <div class="col-sm-8">
                            <div class="inputer">
                                <div class="input-wrapper">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="no_of_admission_per_year" value="<?php echo $row['no_of_admission_per_year']; ?>">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-sm-4 control-label"><?php echo get_phrase('no_of_semester');?></label>
                        <div class="col-sm-8">
                            <div class="inputer">
                                <div class="input-wrapper">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="no_of_semester" value="<?php echo $row['no_of_semester']; ?>">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row example-row">
                        <div class="col-md-3"><?php echo get_phrase('affiliation_start_date'); ?></div><!--.col-md-3-->
                        <div class="col-md-9">
                            <div class="control-group">
                                <div class="controls">
                                    <div class="input-group">
                                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="ion-android-calendar"></i></span>
                                        <div class="inputer">
                                            <div class="input-wrapper">
                                                <input type="text" style="width: 200px" name="affiliation_start_date" class="form-control bootstrap-daterangepicker-basic" value="<?php echo $row['affiliation_start_date']; ?>" />
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div><!--.col-md-9-->
                    </div><!--.row-->

                    <div  class="col-lg-12 form-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-flag-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> <?php echo get_phrase('select_status'); ?></span>

                        <select data-placeholder="Select Program Status" name="status" class="chosen-select">
                                <option disabled selected>Select Program Status</option>
                                <option value="1">Program is Running</option>
                                <option value="0">Program is Not Running</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-5">
                                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> <?php echo get_phrase('edit_programs');?></button>
                                                </div>
                                        </div>
                        </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<?php
endforeach;
?>
```

The result of this code looks like the image below

---

[image: The ajax loaded modal window]

Comment: You should be using your get where in models not views.

Answer (score 0):

you have to bind your select2 when showing up the popup model.

because popup html is loaded only when its called, but the script is called when page is loaded.

Try this...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function showAjaxModal(url)
{
    // SHOWING AJAX PRELOADER IMAGE
    jQuery('#modal_ajax .modal-body').html('<div style="text-align:center;margin-top:200px;"><img src="assets/images/preloader.gif" /></div>');
    $('input[name="affiliation_start_date"]').daterangepicker();
    // LOADING THE AJAX MODAL
    jQuery('#modal_ajax').modal('show', {backdrop: 'true'});
    $(".chosen-select").select2();

    // SHOW AJAX RESPONSE ON REQUEST SUCCESS
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        success: function(response)
        {
            jQuery('#modal_ajax .modal-body').html(response);
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: i am new to javascript and jquery so can you tell me how can i bind my select2 ??... and is that the same problem for the  bootstrap date picker as well ??

Comment: yes in popup if you want any custom element i.e. select, datepicker
you have to bind when you call your popup.

where is your popup code (jquery).

Comment: You can find my popup code right above this section... if you have any suggestion regarding the issue please let me know ... Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Hello ajya ... it doesn't worked for me ... i don't know why ... the modal is load fine but the results are same as previous. but for the normal page apart from modal i need to initialize the javascript at the end of the page by writing 8 lines of javascript code.

Comment: `<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
   Pleasure.init();
   Layout.init();
   $('#programList').DataTable();
   FormsPickers.init();
   FormsSelect.init();
  });
  </script>`

so i tried to implement the bind as my include button code 
`$('input[name="affiliation_start_date"]').FormsPickers.init();`
it doesn't work as well
i also tried to cut init from the code but it seems my badluck is surrounded by my poor knowledge of javascript and ajax 
`$('input[name="affiliation_start_date"]').FormsPickers();`

Answer (score 0):

this is my ajax popup code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function showAjaxModal(url)
{
    // SHOWING AJAX PRELOADER IMAGE
    jQuery('#modal_ajax .modal-body').html('<div style="text-align:center;margin-top:200px;"><img src="assets/images/preloader.gif" /></div>');

    // LOADING THE AJAX MODAL
    jQuery('#modal_ajax').modal('show', {backdrop: 'true'});

    // SHOW AJAX RESPONSE ON REQUEST SUCCESS
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        success: function(response)
        {
            jQuery('#modal_ajax .modal-body').html(response);
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

Comment: put this `$('input[name="affiliation_start_date"]').daterangepicker();` 

aftert `jQuery('#modal_ajax .modal-body').html` line before show.